# troubleshooting a performance issue after converting from .net 2.0 to 4.0

Tags: .net, performance, visual-studio-2010, profiling

I have a 5 year old winforms .net MDI app that i just converted from .net 2.0  to 4.0 using vs 2010... the application now takes about 1.5 minutes to start and open a blank form when starting outside of vs, and about 15 seconds when starting within vs. (there was no noticeable delay in starting app in either scenario prior to uprading to .net4.0 and devexpress 11.2)

Unfortunately, there are a few too many variables here... like we also had to use a new version of the devexpress control library, and xpo persistance layer (orm).

The main form has about 1500 or so controls spreed across 12 tabs of a devexpress tabcontrol. Profiling the application shows that in the form constructor almost 63% of the time is spent in "clr.dll"... and i have now idea how to interpret that.

as a test i built another application with the same tools and dropped 1500 controls on a blank form, and it shows that less than 1 percent of the time in that app is spent in the clr.dll for that form constructor.

This doesn't feel right to me... can anyone make any sense of this or point me in the right direction to continue understanding where all the time is going...

I was ready to just accept the results and say well... we can't do this, but the fact that i can create another devexpress form and drop 1500 controls on it and when i profile it, the results make a lot more sense, the majority of the time in the form constructor is spent in the ControlsCollection.Add function or the control constructors themselves...

any ideas ?

thanks jonathan

[image: Profiler results]
OK...  i turned on Load symbos, and this is what i get now... and i must say it worries me, as i'm running on an intel machine... I also can't find any documentation on thePreStubAmd64 call.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... i appear to have solved my own problem, but i don't understand it all.

Because i had converted the original project from 2008, the target platform in VS 2010 was "Any Cpu" ... (which makes sense to me...). I trying to build a new app that exhibited the same bad performance, i noticed that all my new projects defaulted to x86 and ran great... so...

after playing with the configuration manager and creating a new config for my problem solution that targets x86, my startup time went from like 90 seconds to 9 seconds... and i see no sign of "theStubAMD64" function that was taking up like 80% of my time instantiating the form... wohooo...

so for anyone else converting form 2008 to 2010 and need to run under x64, ya might wanna change the target to x86. (i'm sure i'm missing all sorts of stuff... but i'm happy!)

jonathan

i don't suppose anyone cares to explain why an app would run faster under wow64 than native 64bit...